# Number formatting of statistics

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, fonts

This is how many people have [completed their user profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/9/autobiographer) fields:

[image]

3849 people out of 22354 (or about 17%). Sure, not everyone completes their tombstone, but that number sure is set in a super-huge font. Why? Perhaps to match the super-huge font showing the [number of questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions):

[image]

The choice of font size here is okay since it fits with the design, but surely not in the former case. Moreover, the question count is presented with a (comma) thousands separator, while the badge count is not. There's some inconsistency here that could be updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's indeed HUGE. I changed it from 45px to 120%. The change will be on live after the next production build.